# How to access underscore starting attributes in templates OR Error Variables and attributes may not begin with underscores in Django 2.0?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-views, django-2.0

I have ElasticSearch iterated data like this:

```
(Pdb) data[0]
     {'_index': 'publishserdata-index',
      '_type': 'publishser_data_index', 
      '_id': '35', '_score': 1.0, 
      '_source': {'publisher': 'Admin',
                 'department': 'IT', 
                 'subdepartment': 'Full Stack Developer',
                 'inventory_ID': 'IT003',
                 'title': 'Why Should I Use Celery?', }}
```

I want to get publisher, department, title data.

when I iterate value in templates:-

```
{% for d in data %}
       {{d._source.publisher}}/error
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As that code shows, `data[0]` is a dict. So you use normal dict syntax to access its contents: `data[0]['_source']`, etc.